# ROracle performance issues in Rstudio

Tags: r, oracle, performance, rstudio

I am having massive performance issues when querying an Oracle DB from Rstudio (Pro) using ROracle package.
Basically whenever I run a query:

1. It works (which is a good start)
2. But the session is lagging a lot: I can't even open a file from the RStudio browser until the query is finished, and don't even think of running 2 sessions at the same time because if you do then both of them just freeze completely...

Any idea how this could be improved or any other package anyone could suggest to fetch from Oracle?

Thanks.

Comment: At top of script try adding: `options(connectionObserver = NULL)`. Using `odbc` package (same DBI standard as `ROracle`) Oracle took forever to connect until that line was added as it avoids reading all system and metadata tables into RStudio connections pane.